# Ruby on Rails run at Blogspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogspot

I tried to build a ruby-based website. but I want to start on blogspot which is free for beginners. can the ruby system be placed on blogspot, I am very happy if this happens.

Comment: I don't think blogspot available for rails apps, you can start hosting in heroku.com for starter

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not Blogspot customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2988).

Comment: Well, that just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Blogspot does not support ruby on rails. Even it is just a blogging platform where you already have CMS to serve you. But you should have a development environment.  Please try Heroku.com if you want free.
check this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5 to launch your first application on Heroku.

You can add the following lines after

```
rails generate controller welcome
```

```
rails generate scaffold product name 'price:decimal{7,2}' 
rails db:migrate
```

This will create a sample application where you can do all CRUD operation on product. you can try following

```
rails s
```

Now visit `localhost:3000/products`

After installation on Heroku you will get your url where you can run app and do all CRUD operation. Just try it is very easy to do.

Comment: Thank sir, i will follow your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Ruby on Rails, consider to work with another platform like Wordpress instead. But I think it takes time.